# How to sort timestamp in descending order from text file

Tags: c++

*I have managed to write and read the following data from the text file. However, I would like to know on **how to sort the data according to timestamp in descending order.** My output is as follows*

**My Output (Alarm.txt)**

```
2021-03-23 15:35:45 TD02: Estop status: 1, Battery Alarm deactivated 
2021-03-23 15:35:57 TD02: Estop status: 0, Battery Alarm activated 
2021-03-23 15:36:09 TD02: Estop status: 1, Battery Alarm deactivated  
2021-03-23 15:36:27 TD02: Estop status: 0, Battery Alarm activated    
2021-03-23 15:36:45 TD02: Estop status: 1, Battery Alarm deactivated
```

However, I would like the desired output to be as follows

**Desired output (Alarm.txt)**

```
2021-03-23 15:36:45 TD02: Estop status: 1, Battery Alarm deactivated 
2021-03-23 15:36:27 TD02: Estop status: 0, Battery Alarm activated
2021-03-23 15:36:09 TD02: Estop status: 1, Battery Alarm deactivated
2021-03-23 15:35:57 TD02: Estop status: 0, Battery Alarm activated  
2021-03-23 15:35:45 TD02: Estop status: 1, Battery Alarm deactivated
```

---

I have the following minimal executable code example:

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
//declaring makro for filename. Executed only once on compiletime
#define FILENAME "AlamrLog.txt"


void functionWrite(std::fstream &file)
{
  file.open(FILENAME, std::ios::out | std::ios::app);
  std::string msg{"Battery_Alarm"};
  file << msg << " " << '\n';
  file.close();
}

void functionRead(std::fstream &file)
{
  file.open(FILENAME, std::ios::in);
  std::string msg{};
  int count{1}; //equi. to currentDateTime()

  while ( file >> msg)
   std::cout << "Message #" << count++ << " TD02:... " << msg << '\n';
  file.close();
}

int main()
{
  std::fstream open_file;

  functionWrite(open_file);
  functionRead(open_file);


  std::cout << "Press RETURN to continue";
  std::cin.get();
  return 0;
}
```

*(This post is related to my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66701459/12078969).)*

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Use `std::sort` with a custom comparitor.  Or if on a Unix based system, the `sort` command, and not have to write a program to do this work.

Comment: Hmm I tried research on the std::sort for that, but seems to have no result. Furthermore, the data in the text file is passed as a string

Comment: Show your code! Show everything you tried and explain what failed. "seems to have no result" is not a problem description.

Answer (score -1):

You want to parse every line and split it into two parts , time stamp and message string. Then convert string time to epoch time (it will be a very long digit). Then you can use a map <timestamp,string> or a class of timestamp, string . Over ride the less operator and you should have your sort function working. You can google the steps, generic stuff. Happy coding XD

Comment: Once you "convert string time to epoch time (it will be a very long digit)", you simply sort entries by digitalized timestamp value. `map` is not to perform sorting.

Comment: Internally, map containers keep all their elements sorted by their key following the criterion specified by its comparison object. The elements are always inserted in its respective position following this ordering. : quote http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/insert/

Comment: Also the next logical operation will be timestamp based filtering (i see only 2 status codes so omitting that) map will have a typical problem of not accepting duplicate timestamp so a class with less operator overloaded is better choice in that regard and is open to extension for future( you are not limited to key value pair)

Answer (score -1):

*The Question is related to that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66701459/12078969) and also edited and since a few days waiting for edit approval.*

This is the most compact solution I can come up with using a vector container
(a more flexible array if you like)

It basically

1. reads the whole log file line by line with `std::getline()`
   (So you don't have to mess with time format what so ever)
2. inserts the new line to write on the beginning of the vector
3. writes the whole vector back to the file

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
//declaring makro for filename. Executed only once on compiletime
#define FILENAME "AlamrLog.txt"

void openToRead(std::fstream &file);
void openToWrite(std::fstream &file);
void openToWrite(std::fstream &file, bool trunc); //overloading function 

void functionWrite(std::fstream &file, int &i)
{
  std::string msg{};
  std::vector<std::string> v; //create vector

  openToRead(file);              //call open function
  while(std::getline(file, msg)) //read whole sentence
    v.push_back(msg);            //with getline until loop stop at EOF
  file.close();                  //close file to change read to write

  openToWrite(file);              //call open function
  msg = "Battery Alarm #" + std::to_string(i); //generate string
  v.insert(v.begin(), msg);       //insert msg to beginning of vector
  for(int j{};j < v.size();++j)   //write vector to file
    file << v[j] << '\n';
  file.close();                   //close write file
}

void functionRead(std::fstream &file)
{
  openToRead(file);
  std::string msg{};
  int count{1};

  //gets the whole line, what ever it contains
    while ( std::getline(file, msg))
          std::cout << "Message #" << count++ << " TD02:... " << msg << '\n';
  file.close();
}

int main()
{
  std::fstream open_file;
  int i{0};
  char input{};

  while(true){
    std::cout << "Press RETURN to continue and 'e' to exit";
    std::cin.get(input);
    switch(input){
      case 'e':
        return 0;
      break;
    }

  i++;
  functionWrite(open_file,i);
  functionRead(open_file);
  }
}

void openToRead(std::fstream &file)
{
  file.open(FILENAME, std::ios::in); //open file in read mode
    if(!file.is_open())std::cout << "Impossible to open the file\n";
}

void openToWrite(std::fstream &file,bool trunc)
{
  file.open(FILENAME, std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc); //open file in write mode
    if(!file.is_open())std::cout << "Impossible to open the file\n";
}

void openToWrite(std::fstream &file)
{
  file.open(FILENAME, std::ios::out); //open file in write mode
    if(!file.is_open())std::cout << "Impossible to open the file\n";
}
```